# Standardise telephone number format

Tags: excel, vba, phone-number

I have a column with 32 different phone formats that I need to consolidate into one format type: (###)###-####. The goal is to upload this formatted data into an existing db. I did find some formulas that help but these require helper cell.

I think some of the cells that contain less than 10 digits or more than ten digits will be manually fixed but no decision has been made yet. So, for now, I'll have some cells that have less than or more than the normal phone number (10 characters)

Here is a table of some of the original data and the result I need to see.

```
Original Data       Result
*6.5033E+14     (650)329-670061133
*5.07127E+12        (507)127-2004904
*4.0809E+11     (408)089-787487
*9258254882     (925)825-4882
*6547621             (654)762-1
*310921278      (310)921-278
*415 6995743        (415)699-5743
*209-986-334        (209)986-334
*661-331-2792       (661)331-2792
*(831)383-8650 (1103)       (313)838-6501103
*(415)488-9437 (517)        (415)488-9437517
*(831)383-9452 (32)     (831)383-945232
*(408)927-9482      (408)927-9482
*(000)408-7089      (000)408-7089
*b      
*Oakland
```

Is it possible to create a macro so I won't have to use helper cells with various formulas? Also, I do have cells without a number so I would need a condition to ignore these cells as well.

Comment: Please explain how you get **(650)329-670061133** from **6.5033E+14** ??

Comment: I use the concatenate function to format the cell in this manner. I'm trying to find a way to create a macro so I can avoid having to use helper columns. I presently have a nested substitute function that strips away the parentheses and hyphen. As you can see, in some instances there is an extension number tacked onto the phone number (which is an error of course).

Answer (score 1):

Use this UDF.

```
Function TelFormat(s As String)
    Dim sRp As String, n As Integer
    s = Replace(s, "(", "")
    s = Replace(s, ")", "")
    s = Replace(s, "-", "")
    s = Replace(s, " ", "")
    n = Len(s) - 6
    sRp = WorksheetFunction.Rept("#", n)
    TelFormat = Format(s, "(000)-###-" & sRp)
End Function
```

[image]